# How to get the value from a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating the pulling of data from a CSV File and I ran to this problem: "Overflow"

My goal is to get the size of a server on a specific cell in excel. Sample value is "42164.69 MB"

```
 Dim SizeAsText As String

SizeAsText = CInt(Split(Workbooks(CustName).Worksheets("DB Info").Range("B5"), " ")(0)) * 0.001

Workbooks(RAF).Worksheets("RA").Range("B60").Value = SizeAsText
```

from my code, I should be getting 42.16469. But I am getting the "overflow" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide the index for SizeAsText e.g. `Value =SizeAsText(0)`

Comment: Thanks @MiguelH, correct me if I am wrong, excel usually gets the first value as default? is that correct? That is why my assumption was it will get the 4214.69. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:

```
SizeAsText = CInt(Split(Workbooks(CustName).Worksheets("DB Info").Range("B5"), " ")(0)) * 0.001
```

Should be:

```
SizeAsText = CLng(Split(Workbooks(CustName).Worksheets("DB Info").Range("B5"), " ")(0)) * 0.001
```

Comment: Be aware that CLng will truncate the value, you might want to use CDbl instead to get a decimal value (before applying the `* 0.001`). Be also aware that CDbl use the system decimal separator, which may or may not change, if you are sure that the decimal separator in the file is always `.`(dot), you can use [Val](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) to do the convertion, and the code will be : `SizeAsText = Val(Workbooks(CustName).Worksheets("DB Info").Range("B5")) * 0.001`

Comment: @VincentG, just the result I was looking for! Thank you for your short lesson. THIS WILL HELP A LOT IN MY FUTURE PROJECTS. I cannot thank you enough.